# Intellij - How do I change the file extension of a file from within the IDE?

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

Intellij - How do I change the file extension of a file from within the IDE?  I want to change a file from .java to .groovy, but I can't figure out how from inside the IDE.

Comment: hmm interesting.  I can't find a way to do it.  So just create a new file with the new extension, copy the stuff over, or just do it from the command line.

Comment: A good question with absolutely senseless answers :-(

Answer (score 10):

Use project view -> right click on file -> refactor -> rename file

By default there is no shortcut assigned to this refactoring (Using Intellij 12.1.6)
Refactor | Rename as CrazyCoder mentioned does not work for me. The file extension is not displayed.

Comment: Extremely bad answer. You can easily check that this way is impossible to change the ***extension*** of the file, the Project view sees only names of code files, not extensions.

Comment: @Gangnus, the point of this answer is that there are two "rename" actions: _Rename_ (Shift + F6) and _Rename file_ (no shortcut) and the latter includes the extension.

Comment: @ArturKlesun OK, agreed. Not impossible, but extremely inconvenient. For Project view still does not show extensions.

Answer (score 3):

Use **Refactor** | **Rename File…**.

This action has no default shortcut, but you can [assign one in the Keymap settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxPtA.png).

[image: rename file]

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't seem to allow me to change the file extension, only the name of the class.

Comment: Updated my reply to clarify where you should use Refactor | Rename.

Comment: It doesn't work no matter where I try to run it. Says "xxxx.groovy is invalid identifier" when run from navigation bar or project view. The only way idea can help you to do it is "Show in explorer" and renaming it there. Can avoid manual navigation at least.

Comment: Another senseless answer. Do you consider the author of the question a fool? Why do you think he did not try that obvious solution? Why haven't you tried yourself? You can easily check that this way is impossible to change the extension of the file, the Project view sees only names of code files, not extensions.